# Custom template support for custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, templates

I know I can use `single-{posttype}.php` but can I use something like `single-{custom-post-type-slug}.php` to target a specific custom post type post? Or is there another way like a custom template which I can select from the admin? It doesn't seem to work on custom post type edit sreen.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

Custom Post Types use two different template files, depending on context.

For [custom post type single post display](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Single_Post_display):

- `single-{posttype}.php`
- `single.php`
- `index.php`

For [custom post type archive display](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Post_Types_display):

- `archive-{posttype}.php`
- `archive.php`
- `index.php`

In both cases, `{posttype}` is the **custom post type `$slug`**, as-defined in the [`register_post_type( $slug, $args )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) call.

Comment: This does not answer the question, sorry. I want to target specific cpt post, not the generic `cpt` template.

Comment: Then you need to re-word your question to clarify exactly what you're after. `single-{custom-post-type-slug}.php` is quite unclear. Perhaps you mean `single-{CPT-post-slug}.php`?